# Bivariate random variables

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be a pair of bivariate Gaussian random variables with zero mean. Let u = x+ay and v=bx+y. Find out constant a and b which make u independent of x and v independent of y?
I don't know how to start.

Comment: Are you sure you got this statement right? It does not make much sense to me: $u$ can never be independent of $x$. It would be reasonable to ask when $u$ and $v$ are independent of **each other**.

Comment: It wasn't stated that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.  If they are correlated, then such $a$ and $b$ do exist.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following two observations:

1. Two Gaussian random variables are independent iff they are uncorrelated
2. A linear combination of Gaussian random variables is a Gaussian random variable.